# When is join tree selectivity = 1?

Tags: database, join, relational-algebra

I'm trying to understand some examples from a textbook regarding join trees, their cardinality, selectivity, and cost.

The cost function is given as follows:

[image: Cost Function]

The statistics for the example are

- R1 = 10
- R2 = 100
- R3 = 1000
- f_(1,2) = 0.1
- f_(2,3) = 0.2

What trips me up is that they then say: assume f_ij=1 for all other combinations.

What does this say about other combinations? Does this mean that joining R_2 and R_3 won't produce any results because they don't share any attributes? If they don't share any attributes, wouldn't that make the result an empty set?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: If two relations do not share any attributes then a join degenerates to Cartesian Product; then the result won't be empty (unless either of the relations are empty). The cardinality of the result will be the product of the cardinalities of the arguments. If the relations do share attributes, then you must compare each tuple in one against each tuple in the other; it's the same amount of work whether or not the result is empty. Obviously the cost will be much less if the relations have suitable indexes, but seems the exercise isn't considering indexes(?) Perhaps that's next chapter.